# In what case you would say "I speak things" instead of "I say things"?

Tags: phrases

In what case you would say "I speak things" instead of "I say things"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I speak things* means something like *I proclaim things*, pertaining authority, like *I speak things into existence*. *I say things* is way of normal discourse.

> - Canadians say things like "a" every second word.
> - I speak things I do not see as though they were.
> - I speak to my dog and he obeys.

but

> I speak things faster than I think.

Which is only a problem if the things I speak have certain authority or effect. Usually I would use this phrase if the things I spoke had a proclaiming character and hurt a situation or person.

Comment: Thank You soooo much, Ralph, for these explanations. "I would use this phrase if the things I spoke had a proclaiming character and hurt a situation or person" - Do You think a situation when I give a toast at my friend's birthday party or a case with a professor teaching (lecturing) from a platform (lecturing desk) would also fall into that kind of category?

Comment: @brilliant - What I meant is that speaking faster than I think usually hurts. A toast is a perfect situation to speak things - proclaim positive things over the future of a person. It is, if you are not careful and speak faster than you think, a perfect situation to intimidate or hurt that person. So both could apply.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I could say "my best man spoke wonderful things at my wedding" or "today the professor spoke things I could not understand"?  Those are awkward at best, or even potentially non-native sounding.  Even "I speak things faster than I think" sounds awkward to me and "I speak things I do not see..." is certainly archaic.

Comment: @kosmonaut - not archaic, biblical and therefore most up to date (Heb 11:1). ;-) Unusual, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

In ordinary speech, "speak" does not take a direct object. You can be speaking, you can speak *to* somebody, but to "speak words" or "speak a message" is unusual and I would say literary. 
(I except idioms like "speak my mind" and "speak the truth", and also the construction "Speak English", where the language looks syntactically like a direct object, but I actually think it is a verbal modifier, like an adverb).

Comment: Well, Colin, I know that all too well, but what really interests me here is in what case people would say exactly this word-combination "speak things" (not "speak my mind", "speak the truth", etc.) I know "speak" usually doesn't take a direct object and it sounds a little strange or literary, yet I still want(ed) to know in what case people would still say "speak things". I think Ralph already answered my question quite well.

Comment: Well, I would never say "I speak things" unless I was being deliberately pompous or archaic.

Comment: @brilliant: I am inclined to agree with Coline Fine.  Per your question, I would (almost?) never *say* "speak things" at all.  I might *write* "speak things", but even that would be potentially archaic and certainly affected writing.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: What about that joke when a patient who is also a professor in some university comes to visit a psychiatrist and says, 'Doctor, I think I have a problem: whenever I speak things it just looks to me that I speak, but in fact I remain silent! All my students complain that I don't say a word during a lesson. Yesterday, at my friend's party, when I was giving a toast I thought I was quite good at it, but all my friends kept staring at me waiting for me to say something... Doctor, help me! What should I do?' Doctor (after a while) says, 'So, how can I help you sir?'

Comment: @brilliant: I would laugh... but if I retold it I would replace "speak things" with "speak" or "say things" :)

Comment: But as Kosmonaut says, I would not expect even a professor to talk about "speaking things" in that context, so for me the joke fails.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: But isn't it like in this joke the patient realizes that he has a problem SPEAKING THINGS (i.e. saying things aloud in public, in front of a big audience), while he still thinks he's okay SAYING THINGS (saying something to one or two persons - just like what he was doing it here in front of the doctor)?

Comment: @Colin Fine: Colin, I don't understand, Why for You the joke fails? The joke is spoken from the point of view of the professor's inner world, i.e. his mind. It is all his thoughts and words in that joke. What we are shown in that joke is how he perceives all things - even things about his own words and actions.

Comment: For me, "speaking things" is not something that even a professor would say to himself to mean "saying things in public". It simply does not have that meaning for me, without considerably more context.

Comment: "...without considerably more context" - I am sorry for being, perhaps, too annoying, but your last words give me some hope that "speaking tings" is still possible under some very very specific circumstances, some broader context. Can you, please, try to come up with such context?

Comment: No. I think I would always find it unnatural. The "considerably more context" meant "in order to find the particular meaning in it that the joke requires".